# Long Text Field over 255 Characters gets truncated

Tags: sql, ms-access

Not sure why my field in my query is getting truncated upon the return of the result. The value is being stored in the field, but gets truncated by access to help with "performance". I have reviewed multiple forums and SO posts to no avail.

Problems listed at link do not apply, [Aggregation, Uniqueness, Union, Format Property, Row Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab6c5054-b311-4de8-b0f3-93f3fe9adbed/dataset-scalar-function-returning-only-255-chars-from-access-memo-field?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

What is wrong with my query? Instructions field in the Customer table is the one that is getting truncated.
[image: Image of the Query from Access]

Here is the raw query generated by access:

```
SELECT Task.ID, Task.TaskID, Task.TaskName, Task.TypeID, TaskType.TaskTypeName, Task.CustomerID, Customer.CustomerName, Customer.OnHold, Customer.Blacklisted, Customer.CustomerEngagementRecieved, Customer.AutoEmail, Customer.SpecialInstructions, Customer.Instructions, Task.QuoteRequired, Task.PriorityID, Priority.Priority, Task.Min, Task.Max, Task.Projected, Task.DeadlineDate, Task.ResourceID, Resource.ResourceName, Resource.Email, Resource.Extension, Task.Description, Task.StatusID, Status.Status, Task.DeveloperLog, Task.TaskPOCID, POC.Phone, POC.Email, Task.OtherPOC, Task.OtherPOCPhone, Task.OtherPOCEmail, Task.FolderPath, Task.StopBilling, Task.Premium, Task.EntryDate, Task.CompleteDate, Task.AssignedBy, Task.SettingsID, Settings.AutoEmail
FROM TaskType 
    INNER JOIN (Status 
    INNER JOIN (Settings 
    INNER JOIN (Resource 
    INNER JOIN (Priority 
    INNER JOIN (Customer 
    INNER JOIN (Task 
    INNER JOIN POC ON Task.TaskPOCID = POC.POCID) 
        ON Customer.CustID = Task.CustomerID) 
        ON Priority.PriorityID = Task.PriorityID) 
        ON Resource.ResourceID = Task.ResourceID) 
        ON Settings.SettingsID = Task.SettingsID) 
        ON Status.StatusID = Task.StatusID) 
        ON TaskType.TTID = Task.TypeID;
```

`

Comment: How do you know it's not simply a display issue?

Comment: Because i am using the same type of field as another long text field. DeveloperLog is on the main table and Long Text. I copied this same form object and changed the control source to the Instructions Field. Truncation still occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the sounds of it, Access just sometimes will ALWAYS truncate the field no matter what the settings. There is a way to force access to show the entire field though, by using the [DLOOKUP()](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6330dbfc-4a1f-4b31-b139-90b6f7ff9327/report-memo-field-truncated-to-255-characters?forum=accessdev)  function instead of using a Control Source.

Here is the Answer to my current Issue for reference, 
`=DLOOKUP("Instructions", "Customer", "CustID=" & [CustomerID])`

Answer (score 0):

Have a close read of this - http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html something in your set up will causing the truncation.

If it's when you cut and paste the query results that can also be mis-leading. When you say a Long Text are these linked tables?

I'd also rename your Min and Max fields as they are reserved words and may cause access to think you are aggregating your data.

Comment: That link is almost the same exact copy of the same link i posted in my question. is there something specific I'm missing? Ive read it over thoroughly before and none of them apply. By Linked do you mean joined? if so then yes they are.

Comment: Just noticed your field names - and have edited the answer,

Comment: Even with changing the names to Min --> MinHours, Max ->> MaxHours, the problem still persists

Comment: In table design view what type of field does Access think the field is? It should be seen as a Memo. If it says text then it will not handle it correctly,

Comment: this is MS Access 2013, so i'm using Long Text. There is no memo

Comment: Long Text = Memo, just a different name now

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if you have unique vales set to yes - but that would normally add the DISTINCT word to your query. Any chance of uploading a sample database?

Comment: I have checked the query properties and neither the Unique Values nor the Unique Records were set to yes. I just found an article on the MSDN saying that sometimes you just cant get it to not truncate. ill post the workaround